# How do you explicitly delete a SQLite database created with the sqldf library in an R script

Tags: r, sqldf

I have created an R function to perform subsetting, summaries, densities, and plotting.  I was initially assigning out the subsets to my workspace in RStudio but I started running into memory constraints.  The latest revision is attempting to store the summarized observation counts in a SQLite database vs. exporting the subsets as their own dataframes.  The theory was that this would utilize less memory.  In order to perform this process I created a new database in my function as in:

```
sqldf("attach 'mydb' as new")
sqldf("create table TotalsTbl as select 'resimrr' as name, count(*) as count from resimrr", dbname="mydb")
sqldf("insert into TotalsTbl select 'resimrrquan' as name, count(*) as count from resimrrquan", dbname="mydb")
```

I then create a few tables, and populate them as the function processes.  Finally I export the query results of SQLite Tables to dataframes that I then assign out to my workspace.

This provides the expected result:

```
sqldf("select * from TotalsTbl, dbname="mydb")
name count
1 resimrr 95517
2 resimrrquan 93928
```

The challenge now is that the database is persistent.  It is created the first time the function is envoked, it lives in my Rsessions and my workspace and if I run the function again the CREATE TABLE commands fail because the tables already exist.  So the question is how do I delete/clean up 'mydb' after I am through with it in my function?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `dbname = tempfile()` so that it uses an external database rather than memeory?  Is it too slow?

Comment: How about file.remove("mydb") as an sqlite DB is just a file.

Comment: @g-grothendieck, yes the reason I'm not using the tempfile() option is because I kept running out of memory while processing this dataset.

Comment: @jwijffels, got it thanks! This should work for dropping the database (i.e. deleting the file).  It turns out not deleting the db will actually work to my advantage I just needed to modify my approach.  My challenge was that I had no idea where R and the SQLDF package were creating and storing this file on the file system.  Found my answer here - R's working directory, [link](http://tinyurl.com/q8jtg5p)