# Deleting a SQLite database created with the sqldf library in R

Tags: sqldf

Hi I have the same question as this post
[How do you explicitly delete a SQLite database created with the sqldf library in an R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593364/how-do-you-explicitly-delete-a-sqlite-database-created-with-the-sqldf-library-in)

However, the user found the answer in a blog and put the link up but the link no longer works. Like the user, I don't understand where tables are stored and can't delete them. I've used the following commands with no success

```
sqldf("attach 'mydb' as new")
sqldf("create table mytable as SELECT * FROM mytable1", dbname="mydb")
file.remove("mytable")
sqldf("drop table mytable", dbname="mydb")
```

I get the error "sqldf: table mytable1 already in mydb"

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: The drop table line gives the error "sqldf: table mytable1 already in mydb". file.remove("mytable") gives error "cannot remove file 'mytable', reason 'No such file or directory'"